# Issue with wsimport authentication when generating SOAP Java client

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, wsimport

I use the following command to generate web service client files for java.

> wsimport -keep http://test.com/test?wsdl -xauthfile auth.txt

The following was in `auth.txt`

> http://user:password@ip:port//path

But, the `password` was having special characters like `abcw@sdsds`. 
So I was getting wrong format error. So I have encoded password like `abcw%40sdsds`. But, now got authentication error due to wrong password because of parsing.

Is there any ways to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking online I found this bug was actually fixed in the latest version. But I still get the same issue. You can refer to the following links for information on the bug.

https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1101

So I finally made custom HTTP request with NTLM authentication using HTTP Client in Java.

```
String bodyAsString = ""; //Provide Input SOAP Message
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
new NTCredentials("UserName", "Password", "Host", "Domain"));
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("URL"); //Provide Request URL
try 
{
   StringEntity input = new StringEntity(bodyAsString);
   input.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
   post.setEntity(input);
   post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
   post.setHeader("SOAPAction", ""); //Provide Soap action

   org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
   HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
   if (responseEntity != null) 
   {
      return EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
   }
}
```

I got the above solution from the following github link 
https://github.com/sujithtw/soapwithntlm